# Linear isomorphism $f:U_1\to U_2$ with $U_2\subset U_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $U_1,U_2\subset V$ be subspaces of $V$ such that $U_2\subset U_1$ and let $f:U_1\to U_2$ be a linear isomorphism. Prove (or give a counterexample) whether the following holds: $$U_1=U_2$$

I can't think of a counterexample but showing this also seems difficult since if $B_1$ is a Basis of $U_1$, all I know is that $f(B_1)$ is a basis of $U_2\subset U_1$ but that doesn't seem to suffice.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is $U{}{}$?

Comment: Hint:  think of "dimension"

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, $U$ means $V$, I've edited the post.

Comment: @user: See my edit, I had switched two indicies making it appear that I was just repeating your second paragraph, which was not my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $U_1$ and $U_2$ are isomorphic then they have the same dimension, which must be finite because $V$ is finite dimensional.  This means any basis of $U_2$ must also be a basis for $U_1$, so $U_1 = U_2$.

Edit: Per your comment I realized I had my indices switched.  Once the spaces are the same dimension you know that a basis for $U_2$ remains linearly independent when considered as a set of elements in $U_1$, so it's a basis because by dimension is a maximal linearly independent set.  This means $U_1$ is the span of those vectors, as is $U_2$, hence $U_1 = U_2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Since we have finite  dimensional spaces,
$$\dim (U_1/U_2)=\dim U_1 -\dim U_2. $$
Now, since $U_1$ and $U_2$ are isomorphic, they have the same dimension.